# Why do PSQL \z and information_schema.table_privileges show different details?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, psql

I'm stumbling into an accidental DBA role at my current company and SO has been a huge help in getting me set up with useful queries.

I'm currently trying to create some views to assist with UAR (user access review) to satisfy compliance requirements and assist users with troubleshooting access. To do so I'm trying to create a view that lists user names and their privileges on all tables in all schemas in the database. I started with a view against `information_schema.table_privileges` but noticed it was incomplete. If it's relevant, this is in an AWS RDS Postgres implementation.

To dive in, I performed `\z schema_name.table_name` and I got the below output. All looks well: I see the owning role `analytics_owner` with all privileges and six group roles with varying levels of privilege. (All employees and applications accessing the database are granted membership to one of these six roles.)

[image: \z output]

This is also shown by a query against `pg_class`:

[image: pg_class output]

But if I query against `information_schema.table_privileges`, there are no results. (In fact, if I drop the `where relname = '[table]'` clause there are only two tables with detail in the relevant schema in the `table_privileges` output — but there are about a hundred tables in the actual schema.)

[image: information_schema.table_privileges]

The privilege detail from the `\z` command just isn't showing in `information_schema.table_privileges`. I'd prefer to write a view off of `table_privileges` rather than `pg_class` because I wouldn't have to decode and separate the aggregated ACL details. However, it looks like there is something very specific to the `table_privileges` view given that only a very small subset of the actual tables are in there.

Is there a query that produces the same detail in the same format as contained in `information_schema.table_privileges` but takes its data from `pg_class`? Alternatively, what is different about `table_privileges` that makes it not show the full detail, and is there something I can do about the granted privileges to make them visible there for ease in review?

Comment: The data you see in `information_schema` is determined by what role you are when you run the query. Try the query when logged in as a superuser role. If you want to see the query being used for the `information_schema.table_privileges` view then in `psql` do: `\d+ information_schema.table_privileges`

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver! I don't have access to a true superuser role, but this makes perfect sense. That view definition also revealed aclexplode() which looks like it will come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Per Adrian Klaver's comment, the `information_schema` depends on the role you are logged in on when the query was run.

Comment: Besides the role there is another possible source of difference. The content of Information_Schema is defined in ISO-9075 (SQL Standard). It is entirely possible Postgres does not include their extensions  as they are not included in the Standard.  To ensure you have identified everything you need to navigate [pg_catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalogs.html) (not an easy task), but it is fully documented.